# Why in numcases centering is disabled when using texlive2020 in win10

Tags: environments, cases

I found recently in environment numcases centering is diabled, and the displayed result is pushed right. Below is a screenshot of this problem:
[image]

I am using TeXLive2020 in Win10.  How can I solve this problem.

PS:When I compiled this .tex file in Debian Buster, all things go well without trouble.

In order to find the reason, I make a test tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
  A simple example is:
 \begin{numcases} {|x|=}
 x, & for $x \geq 0$\\
-x, & for $x < 0$
 \end{numcases} 
 \end{document}
```

After complied this test file using TeXLive2020, I got
[image]

But when I commented the line ``\usepackage{empheq}", all things go well. So I　am confirmed that the cause of this problem is the conflict of cases and empheq.

Comment: Screenshots of the editor aren't useful. copy the text of a short demo document into your question. Select the code and click on the `{ }` above the editing panel. Your use of numcases is *very VERY* weird - no numbering, and no alignment with `&` but finicky manual spacing instead. Something you don't show is probably causing the flush-right alignment.

Comment: For most cases, it is not the operating system, but the version of latex distribution(s), used latex packages that relates. You can add `\listoffiles` before `\begin{document}`, compile, and then find package version info near the end of `.log` file. Compare the package version info you get in Win 10 and Debian (or append it to your question), you may find some indication.

Comment: I have found the reason of this problem is cause by the conflict in TeXLive2020 of two packages: cases and empheq.

Comment: I doubt that TeXLive2020 LaTeX is different from recent MikTeX LaTeX distribution. With later I can't confirm your claims. Result is the same if `empheq` is loaded or not.

Comment: I get the same as Zarko, I recommend you post a list of verions as mentions above.

Answer (score 1):

Update `cases.sty`. The current version is `2020/03/29 ver 3.2`, and if texlive can't provide it, get it from CTAN.

The conflict fixed then was with `calc.sty`, and the effect wasn't exactly being "pushed right", in that the equation numbers are pushed left from the margin, accompanied by "overfull hbox" warnings. I don't see `calc` loaded in your example, but it gets loaded deep within empheq apparently.

Comment: Calc is loaded in mathtools which is the first thing empheq loads

Comment: I have solved this problem after updated the package cases from 3.1 to 3.2, as Donald Arseneau said. Thanks a lot.